# Dynamically Customizable Group-Based Authorization in Rails

Tags: mysql, permissions, ruby-on-rails-3.2, role-base-authorization

Currently, in my app there are just 3 roles visitors can have:

- `admin` that has all privileges
- `user` that can can perform several actions about him/her-self within the system
- `guest` that can just watch and send bug reports

Everything is primitively implemented, as follows: in a DB each user has a field where his being `admin` (stands for `2` in the field) or `user` (`1`) is indicated, and in the `application_controller.rb` it is just checked `if logged_in? && current_user.DB_FIELD == 2` (or `> 0`), and in the necessary controller there occurs a `before_filter` check, etc.

However, such a simple implementation worked great till recently when we decided to extend the functionality of the system, that is, partly, to allow admin to join users into groups, but there are some moments. For better understanging of what I am going to ask, let me describe the situation from the way I see it (maybe you can suggest something much better and logical):

1. I am an admin. I open `/groups`, and see a list of groups.

   - What is a group? A group, on the one hand, is a *set of permissions*, and on the other hand, is a *combination of users* that should have the same permissions within my app.
   - What is a permission? A permission is *one* action that each user of the group it assigned to can perform.
2. I want to unite new users in one group, but this group doesn't exist. So I click the button (which stands for `/groups/new`), and the Create Group window pops up. There, I have a textfield for a group name, a bulk of checkboxes, each stands for a permission, a field for adding users, and a Save button. I write the group name, check all the permissions I want to assign to this group, add users to this group (I am going to implement this through ajax search: starting typing a user's name, he/she appears, click Enter, and one user is added, then repeat these actions if needed - is it an OK approach?), and click Save.
3. Ok, I got a new group with several users. But stop, I realized I forgot to add one more person! I return to the Edit Group window (`/groups/edit`), and refill the misfilled fields. Click Save - and again some magic (I mean, update operations over the DB).

And so, what I have at the final stage? I can freely c/r/u/d the groups, managing users and permissions in them, and perform it in a very GUI-driven way (I mean, checkboxes, ajax search field, etc.)

For two weeks I have been googling/stackoverflowing/scrutinizing info about rails role- and group-based authorizations; have found a lot of solutions like cancan, [easy_roles](https://github.com/platform45/easy_roles), [troles](https://github.com/kristianmandrup/troles), etc. gems, but cannot find in any of them how to implement a group-based approach, which is dynamic (or customizable? or dynamically customizable?). The only thing that really 100% suits my needs is a **redmine** permission and permission group approach, but it is overcomplicated due to its over9000-functionality, so I couldn't even fully understand how it is implemented, let alone implement it on my own.

And the questions are (assuming that the set of permissions is *permanent* so can be hardcoded, and the set of groups is absolutely *free*; also, if the user doesn't belong to any group he/she has default user permissions; moreover, permissions are not just for c/r/u/d operations, but also for the manually created methods):

1. What is the *best* way to implement the above mentioned system? Any existing yet not found by me gem or approach?
2. How to painlessly-for-scalability store the permissions and the permission groups? A bitmask, or separate permission, permission-to-group assignment, and group tables?
3. How to painlessly put users into groups? A group field in the user's DB row, or a separate user-to-group assignment table?

Preferably, that the permissions assigned to the group the user being added to, *instantly*, without any user relogins, apply to him.

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

Through several nights I finally came to a solution, which is, to my mind, rather easy yet powerful, but obviously not the best (but still an) implementation.

So, we have now +1 tables, which is of groups, where the columns are `id`, `name`, and `permission`. The last column is a usual integer which represents all the permissions in a decimal number.

The permissions are "aliased" in the controller: e.g. `1` stands for `can_manage_smth`, `2` stands for `can_view_smth`, etc.

The permission choice panel is in the /groups section, and is a simple set of checkboxes, applying an `onchange` action to each we ajaxly perform an `OR` operation with the permission stored in the table (e.g. we select 3 checkboxes standing for the values of `1`, `8`, and `16`, then we get in our table `25`, which is, in turn, a result of `1 | 8 | 16`).

So answering my questions:

1. Not the best but still a solution.
2. It almost does not affect the scalability because adding a new permission (which is a very rare action) will just demand a new alias of the permission and its before_filter checkings in the beginning of the controller. And I used a bitmask but not as a binary but just a usual decimal value with which simple binary logic operands can play.
3. No separate user-to-group assignment tables, just a single `group_id` column in a `user` table (which already existed).

Hope everything implemented will work perfectly. If any issues occur, I will indicate here. Also, if any new implementation ideas come.

Anyway, thanks to everybody!